# TWSz Java API current plan status

Tags: java, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

Is it possible to get Current Plan status using Java API? I try to call many methods from ZConnPlan but without success. Maybe is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is currently not available via Java APIs for TWSz.

I suggest to open an RFE to TWSz for it.

If you can provide more details about the scenario you are trying to implement, I can try to find a workaround.

Comment: I want to display status of the current plan that's all. I going to write my own solution: REXX server and SOE commands. It is very simple with SOE.